# Django: how to build an endswith template filter

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I need to render image **adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png** if `file.url` ends with `.ai`.

But if `file.url` ends with other termination like `.png` for exmaple I'll render the image of the object.

I've searching documentation but apparently there is not a `endswith` built in filter.

So I ended up playing with `ifequals` and `slice` filter.

Logic it is the same: "*if string is identical to the last 3 letters do this*".

However, it is not working, as nothing gets displayed.

```
<td>
   {% ifequal cart_item.file.url|default:""|slice:"-3" ".ai" %}

        <img src="{% static 'img/admin/adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png' %}"
                   alt=""
                   class="float-left rounded custom_image">
   {% endifequal %}
 </td>
```

**Note:**

```
<p>{{ cart_item.file.url  }}</p>
```

**HTML renders**:

```
<p>/media/files/working_precisely.ai</p>
```

Also, **adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png** renders correctly if it is put outside if condition.

**Update 1:**

Created my own filter, but gettting error:

***TemplateSyntaxError at /cart/

    endswith requires 2 arguments, 1 provided***

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=False)
@stringfilter
def endswith(value, suffix):
    return value.endswith(suffix)
```

**Template**

```
{% if cart_item.file.url|endswith: ".ai" %}

       <img src="{% static 'img/admin/adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png' %}"
                alt=""
                class="float-left rounded custom_image">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There's an extensive document on creating custom filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Comment: You can [write your own filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/). In fact, then you can use Python stuff like `os.path.splitext()` under the hood, to split off the extension and return whatever is necessary (either False, True, or a custom string identifying the type).

Comment: @xyres Please, see my update.

Comment: Can you give an example value of `cart_item.file.url`

Comment: Forget it, I just saw you problem. Just remove the space between your filter and passed value. So it becomes `{% if cart_item.file.url|endswith:".ai" %}`

Comment: @OmarGonzales see my answer...you were almost there!

Answer (score 5):

You dont need a(nother) custom filter, you already almost had it. Your `|slice:"-3"` did a `[:-3]` slice in python, but you want a `[-3:]` slice. So, beeing just a tiny bit more explicit:

```
{% if object.image.url.lower|slice:"-3:" == "gif" %}
  # note the added : in "-3:", to make it a [-3:]
{% endif %}
```

Though it is not a real `endswith`, strictly spoken (as you will have to adapt your slice length, if your endswith value changes length, ie 4, if checking for "jpeg"), but works quite well, without adding another template filter to your project.